# How can I extract the full audio or get subtitles of GLaDOS's sentences in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I started playing Portal 2 and GLaDOS voice and dialogs are simply amazing.

I would like to hear or read again some of her sentences. Is it possible extracting them in audio or text form, from some Portal 2 files?

Comment: If you want to skip the fun of doing this yourself, all the clips are available on [Portal Wiki](http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/GLaDOS_voice_lines#Portal_2)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [GCFScape](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/index.php?p=26) and open up the Portal 2 content file, found at `\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\pak01_dir.vpk` (for some reason it's unlike TF2 and HL2 which use `.gcf`'s)

There will be a directory structure visible in the program, browse to `\root\sound\vo\` and go nuts with probably close to 1000 audio files in a couple folders:

```
\root
  \sound
    \vo
      \announcer
      \cavejohnson
      \core01  
      \core02  
      \core03
      \glados
      \turret_defective
      \wheatley
```

Cores 1, 2, and 3 are the...

> "space", "fact" and "adventure" spheres, respectively.
>
>  The final JoCo song is `\root\sound\music\portal2_want_you_gone.wav`,

...and some other talking stuff (turrets mostly) are in the `\root\sound\npc\` folder.

Outside of the `.vpk` with the audio files, the subtitle file can be found at `\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\resource\subtitles_english.txt` (or `_czech`, `_danish`...)  You can actually use this to quickly find an audio file by searching for a word or sentence fragment, e.g. "nine":

```
"announcer.openingcourtesy01"   "<clr:250,231,181>Announcer: Good morning. You have been in suspension for nine nine nine... nine nine ni- This courtesy call is to inform you that all test subjects should immediately vacate [FADES OUT]"
```

The related audio file would be in the `.vpk`, `\vo\announcer\openingcourtsey01.wav`

Comment: I did exactly that and it works for all the audio files except the dialogue ones in the vo file. I'm not sure if i did something wrong but I don't think so, the files themselves are very small. Too small for the amount of dialogue in some of them. Are the dialogues locked up some place else some how?

Comment: You must rename the WAV files to MP3.

Comment: @Isaac Are you sure they are *too* small? The speech files use a more efficient codec than the other files.

Comment: Danish?  Seriously?

Comment: I did the same thing over 8306 audio files in all