# Does GLaDOS say anything meaningful when she "gives us the fast version" in Test Chamber 8?

Tags: portal-2

When we enter the testing area, GLaDOS informs us that she has to go attend to the turbines; before she leaves, she sarcastically gives a radically sped up "explanation" of the test we face in the room.  Does she say anything of note in this version? I wouldn't know how to go about manipulating the audio to find out...

Comment: I'm slowing down the file with Audacity, but it is quite a bit hard to understand anything said. I think I heard something about taking people's hats off, but I might be suffering from TF2-induced hat-fever. EDIT: it definitively ends with 'get to sea as soon as I can'.

Comment: You could pull out the wav file using this method http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20498/how-to-extract-full-audio-or-subtitles-of-glados-sentences/20500#20500 Then slow it way down in Audacity

Comment: Some progress: 'And methodically knocking people's hats off. Then I accounted <blank> time, and get to sea as soon as I can'. The blank is not 'Valve' BTW.

Comment: @Arda Xi: The blank doesn't sound like 'down' at all. It is something that resembles 'height' if anything. I'll have to reflect on this one for a bit.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It appears to be a quote from [the first paragraph of Moby Dick](http://books.google.com/books?id=iqbHsfS5UW8C&q=%22and%20methodically%20knocking%20people%27s%20hats%20off%22) (thanks to Billare for figuring that out):

> […], **and methodically knocking people's hats off — then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can.**

The full passage in *Moby Dick*:

[image: Moby Dick opening lines; "knocking hats"]

Comment: But, you know, I'm not sure that my above interpretation is correct, since it _is_ Ishmael, the narrator, who says those lines, not Captain Ahab -- the one with the whale obsession. In the quoted lines I believe Ishmael is remarking on how he becomes unpleasant and anti-social when he's around people and away from sea too long; maybe GLaDOS is saying that being around Chelle, her murderer, and away from maintaing the facilities makes her similarly crazy?

Comment: From the context, it doesn't seem that the sped-up line was actually supposed to have some deep meaning, since it should be an explanation needed to complete the test. I guess it was just a reference by an employee that happened to like the book.

"Ohhh, no. The turbines again.  I have to go.  Wait. This next test DOES require some explanation. Let me give you the fast version. [fast gibberish]"

Comment: Melville, Machiavelli...at least a fairly good library survived armageddon.

Comment: @Nick T Where does she quote Machiavelli? I don't quite remember.

Comment: @Billare: Wheatley mentions it when he pretends not to be paying attention to you at a moment (can't mention why because there are no spoiler tags for comments xP): "Wheatley: Anyway. Just finished the last one. The hardest one. Machiavelli. Do not know what all the fuss was about. Understood it perfectly. Have you read that one?"

Comment: There is an achievement involving a lost ship.  Could it be related to this message?

Comment: @Jesse the achievement with the lost ship is related to things at the end of HLEp2

Comment: @danielkza I doubt Valve would put something this unrelated up just randomly. It has some meaning.

Answer (score 22):

By slowing it down, and working off of danielkza's suggestions, I've think it's this:

> And methodically knocking people's hats off. Then I found it high time to get to the sea, as soon as I can.

Here's a slowed down version if you want to hear it for yourself: [slowed.ogg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26426/slowed.ogg)

Or on YouTube:

Comment: I think this version sounds quite a bit clearer: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24886021/portal2_glados_slowed.ogg

Comment: It seems that this line comes from _[Moby Dick](http://books.google.com/books?id=XV8XAAAAYAAJ&dq=methodically%20knocking%20people's%20hats%20off%20moby&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q=methodically%20knocking%20people's%20hats%20off%20moby&f=false)_, the first chapters of it in fact.   So is GLaDOS obliquely saying that Chelle is her white whale or something, the thing she's obsessed on catching and killing?

Comment: @Billare: it seems you're right, I thought 'high' was to obvious and it was actually something else.

Comment: @Billare It's Chell by the way, not Chelle.

Comment: @danielkza That link is now broken.

Answer (score 3):

You can slow this down in game, one of the recent changes by Valve is that now when you use `sv_cheats 1; host_timescale 0.5` it also slows down the sound and not only the game. Playing with that `0.5` value should allow you to hear what she is saying. Just don't forget to put it back to default or you won't get any achievements, thus use `host_timescale 1; sv_cheats 0` afterwards.

Comment: Just a hint, I tried some values in Audacity, and the one that seemed to be the best match was a 75% slowdown, so a `host_timescale` of `0.25` should be good enough. The problem is the pitch will probably be completely distorted, something Audacity can (awesomely) correct, unlike the game.

Comment: @danielkza: Maybe; it won't sound like GLaDOS anymore, it will more likely be a low male voice now.