# What are all the facts that Core 3 babbles about in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I just finished Portal 2 and found the facts by Core 3, the "fact" core, quite humorous and informative (I don't believe him).  Since time was short, I couldn't listen to all the facts he might say.

Does anyone have a collection of all the facts Core 3 can say?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

All the facts can be found in the subtitles file at `\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\resource\subtitles_english.txt` (or `_czech`, `_danish`...).  Open it up and search for bits of what you remember, e.g. "dental".

[See this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20498/how-to-extract-full-audio-or-subtitles-of-glados-sentences/20500#20500) if you want to know how to extract the sound files.

- Rats cannot throw up.
- Honey does not spoil.
- The billionth digit of Pi is 9.
- The square root of rope is string.
- A gallon of water weighs 8.34 pounds
- Dental floss has superb tensile strength.
- An ostrich's eye is bigger than its brain.
- Hot water freezes quicker than cold water.
- Polymerase I polypeptide A is a human gene.
- The Sun is 330,330 times larger than Earth.
- The moon orbits the Earth every 27.32 days.
- A nanosecond lasts one billionth of a second.
- To make a photocopier, simply photocopy a mirror.
- Humans can survive underwater. But not for very long.
- The average adult body contains half a pound of salt.
- Volcano-ologists are experts in the study of volcanoes.
- Cellular phones will not give you cancer. Only hepatitis.
- Avocados have the highest fiber and calories of any fruit.
- The atomic weight of Germanium is seven two point six four.
- China produces the world's second largest crop of soybeans.
- Human tapeworms can grow up to twenty-two point nine meters.
- 89% of magic tricks are not magic. Technically, they are sorcery.
- Iguanas can stay underwater for twenty-eight point seven minutes.
- Every square inch of the human body has 32 million bacteria on it.
- The average life expectancy of a rhinoceros in captivity is 15 years.
- At the end of The Seagull by Anton Chekhov, Konstantin kills himself.
- According to most advanced algorithms, the world's best name is Craig.
- Whales are twice as intelligent, and three times as delicious, as humans.
- At some point in their lives 1 in 6 children will be abducted by the Dutch.
- Tungsten has the highest melting point of any metal, at 3,410 degrees Celsius.
- The first person to prove that cow's milk is drinkable was very, very thirsty.
- Raseph, the Semitic god of war and plague, had a gazelle growing out of his forehead.
- Gently cleaning the tongue twice a day is the most effective way to fight bad breath.
- Avocados have the highest fiber and calories of any fruit. They are found in Australians.
- The Mexican-American War ended in 1848 with the signing of the Treaty of Guadalupe Hidalgo.
- According to Norse legend, thunder god Thor's chariot was pulled across the sky by two goats.
- The value of Pi is the ratio of any circle's circumference to its diameter in Euclidean space.
- Edmund Hillary, the first person to climb Mount Everest, did so accidentally while chasing a bird.
- The first commercial airline flight took to the air in 1914. Everyone involved screamed the entire way.
- The plural of surgeon general is surgeons general. The past tense of surgeons general is surgeonsed general.
- Marie Curie invented the theory of radioactivity, the treatment of radioactivity, and dying of radioactivity.
- The occupation of court jester was invented accidentally, when a vassal's epilepsy was mistaken for capering.
- In Greek myth, Prometheus stole fire from the Gods and gave it to humankind. The jewelry he kept for himself.
- Dreams are the subconscious mind's way of reminding people to go to school naked and have their teeth fall out.
- In Greek myth, the craftsman Daedalus invented human flight so a group of Minotaurs would stop teasing him about it.
- Before the Wright Brothers invented the airplane, anyone wanting to fly anywhere was required to eat 200 pounds of helium.
- In 1879, Sandford Fleming first proposed the adoption of worldwide standardized time zones at the Royal Canadian Institute.
- In 1948, at the request of a dying boy, baseball legend Babe Ruth ate seventy-five hot dogs, then died of hot dog poisoning.
- While the submarine is vastly superior to the boat in every way, over 97% of people still use boats for aquatic transportation.
- Roman toothpaste was made with human urine. Urine as an ingredient in toothpaste continued to be used up until the 18th century.
- Before the invention of scrambled eggs in 1912, the typical breakfast was either whole eggs still in the shell or scrambled rocks.
- The Tariff Act of 1789, established to protect domestic manufacture, was the second statute ever enacted by the United States government.
- During the Great Depression, the Tennessee Valley Authority outlawed pet rabbits, forcing many to hot glue-gun long ears onto their pet mice.
- William Shakespeare did not exist. His plays were masterminded in 1589 by Francis Bacon, who used a Ouija board to enslave play-writing ghosts.
- Pants were invented by sailors in the sixteenth century to avoid Poseidon's wrath. It was believed that the sight of naked sailors angered the sea god.
- Diamonds are made when coal is put under intense pressure. Diamonds put under intense pressure become foam pellets, commonly used today as packing material.
- Contrary to popular belief, the Eskimo does not have one hundred different words for snow. They do, however, have two hundred and thirty-four words for fudge.
- Halley's Comet can be viewed orbiting Earth every seventy-six years. For the other seventy-five, it retreats to the heart of the sun, where it hibernates undisturbed.
- It is incorrectly noted that Thomas Edison invented 'push-ups' in 1878. Nikolai Tesla had in fact patented the activity three years earlier, under the name 'Tesla-cize.'
- The automobile brake was not invented until 1895. Before this, someone had to remain in the car at all times, driving in circles until passengers returned from their errands.
- The most poisonous fish in the world is the orange ruffy. Everything but its eyes are made of a deadly poison. The ruffy's eyes are composed of a less harmful, deadly poison.
- In 1862, Abraham Lincoln signed the Emancipation Proclamation, freeing the slaves. Like everything he did, Lincoln freed the slaves while sleepwalking, and later had no memory of the event.
- The Schrodinger's cat paradox outlines a situation in which a cat in a box must be considered, for all intents and purposes, simultaneously alive and dead. Schrodinger created this paradox as a justification for killing cats.
- In Victorian England, a commoner was not allowed to look directly at the Queen, due to a belief at the time that the poor had the ability to steal thoughts. Science now believes that less than 4% of poor people are able to do this.
- If you have trouble with simple counting, use the following mnemonic device: one comes before two comes before 60 comes after 12 comes before six trillion comes after 504. This will make your earlier counting difficulties seem like no big deal.

Comment: I'm not sure we can host that file directly. Maybe expand on the procedure instead?

Comment: @ fail badp do you mean why we they use that `.vpk` file instead of plain simple files?

Comment: @Shek, we just had a minor concern to be blanket copying a bunch of content and posting it.  This is from a file that is **not** in the `.vpk` in any event.

Comment: yeah i just found that its a simple `.txt` file at `"C:\Program Files\Valve\Portal 2\portal2\resource\subtitles_english.txt"`

Comment: rats can't throw up, unless they have pyloric stenosis

Comment: "To make a photocopier, simply photocopy a mirror." Sounds legit.

Answer (score 18):

The Fact Sphere has more lines than there is time for it to say them. Here's a YouTube video of them all: