# How do I extract Portal 2 sound effects?

Tags: portal-2

Okay, so I have Portal 2 on my PC. I would like to use one of its sound effects for a little project, so I started searching the installed files. Well, eventually I found a bunch of "sound" files. I tried to run them, but apparently I can't.

When I go to properties, the file type says: *Sound on format AU (.snd)*

I don't get it (is the file .au or .snd?), how can I use such file? How could I convert it to, say, .mp3?

Comment: Can you tell us where you found the .snd files? Most, if not all of the game's sound files are in WAVE format.

Comment: In a folder called "reslist"?

Comment: On a lark, I popped a couple of those .snd files open with vim... Turns out, they're just text files, no audio data. Your search continues. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate or at least it could be useful for your problem too: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20498/how-to-extract-full-audio-or-subtitles-of-glados-sentences

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All the sound files in the game are in the WAV format, stored within the VPK (Valve Package) files.

Use [GCFScape](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/index.php?p=26) and open up the Portal 2 content file, found at `\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\pak01_dir.vpk` (for some reason it's unlike TF2 and HL2 which use `.gcf`'s)

There will be a directory structure visible in the program, browse to `\root\sound\` and look through the subdirectories for sound effects.  Some sound like throwbacks to Portal 1, and others seem like total cruft from HL2, but everything should be in there, though with perhaps confusing names.

Comment: For Portal 1: The same process but with the "\Steam\SteamApps\common\Portal\portal\portal_pak_dir.vpk" file.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). Not only can it play all the waves, but it can convert them as well.

It has a convert option in the File menu.

Comment: VLC is great.[]

Comment: Apparently VLC won't play the file. And when I convert it, the output is also unplayable.