# Where is Portal 2's excursion funnel sound?

Tags: portal-2

I am looking for Portal 2's excursion funnel sounds. Where could I find them? I need them (if multiple) for a little project I am making. I already used the steps from [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21445/how-do-i-extract-portal-2-sound-effects) and I cannot seem to find what I need. I just got bumped into some strange HL2(?) sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excursion funnel sounds are stored in `\steamapps\common\portal 2\portal2\pak01_dir.vpk`. [Open the file with GCFScape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/21445/181240) and browse to `sound\vfx`. The files are named `player_enter_tbeam_lp_##.wav` and `player_enter_tbeam_ss_lp_##.wav`. (Replace ## with sound number).

[image: Excursion funnel sounds in GCFScape]