# After beating the Portal 2 single player campaign, how do I listen to the ending song again?

Tags: xbox-360, portal-2

Is there a way to listen to the ending song again after I have beat the game?  Other than the obvious way of beating it again.

Comment: I assume it's on the internet somewhere. Youtube probably.

Comment: I'm sure it is on youtube as well.  I was wondering if there was a way to get to it in the game.

Comment: I don't know if this works for xbox but on the PC you can do that by typing "map sp_a5_credits" in the console

Comment: @Air - 360 users can't access the console.

Comment: @Raven-Dreamer should have bought it on the PC then :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Youtube's probably your best bet.

Alternatively, you could manually save your game directly before the final boss fight. You'll have to beat the boss and go through the ending cutscenes again, but it's shorter than beating the *whole* game an Nth time.

Answer (score 16):

> **PC ONLY :(**

If you want to see the whole ending sequence and song, in-game, open the console <kbd>~</kbd> and  run the command `map sp_a5_credits`

You can extract the music as well using [this method](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20498/how-to-extract-full-audio-or-subtitles-of-glados-sentences/20500#20500).  Or you could probably just download it, the music's plastered all over the internet anyways.

Comment: "You can extract the music as well using this method." Not for the Xbox 360 version you can't.

Answer (score 12):

Valve is making the soundtrack from Portal 2, entitled ["Songs To Test By"](http://www.thinkwithportals.com/music.php), available to download free.

You may need to wait for the correct volume to be released, but it will (should?) be there eventually.

**Update:** Soundtrack Volume 3 was recently released and includes "Want you gone". Plus there is a link to it as a ringtone.

Comment: Specifically, it's `Portal2-13-Want_You_Gone.mp3` from Volume 3 or the Complete set.  As a side note, the singing turret is `Portal2-12-Cara_Mia_Addio.mp3` from the same volume.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to watch the credits again, you can select Single Player, then Developer Commentary, then scroll all the way down to "Chapter 10 - The Credits".

Then the credits and the song will roll again!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "New Game", scroll all the way through the levels again, and press "End Credits" or just download it on Spotify.