# Where can I find the turret voiceovers?

Tags: portal

I am looking for the turret voice overs from Portal in the following file:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\portal content.gcf`

I've extracted this using GCFScape, but they don't seem to be in the sound folder with all the other sound files.. I don't want to download them from YouTube as I will have to split them into `.wav` files, and won't be as high quality.

Where are they located?

Comment: For Portal 2 sounds, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20498/how-to-extract-full-audio-or-subtitles-of-glados-sentences/20500#20500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The turret voiceovers are actually in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\portal english.gcf` in the `\root\portal\sound\npc\turret_floor\` directory.

Comment: Ah perfect, I didn't see that file, thanks!