# Where can I find a transcript of Portal 2 dialogue?

Tags: portal-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract full audio or subtitles of GLaDOS sentences?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20498/how-to-extract-full-audio-or-subtitles-of-glados-sentences)

I'm trying to find a list of the dialogue in Portal 2 (all the quotes, not just the popular ones, those I can find easily enough on wikiquotes or the like), but I haven't been able to find anything aside from a couple youtube videos.

Said videos are less than ideal since I have to listen to a bunch of it to find a particular quote, and it includes many variations on what's basically the same line (as the announcer has 7 or so different variations on "Nuclear core overheating").

Does anyone know where I could find a transcript of the dialogue in portal 2?

Comment: Here it is: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20498/how-to-extract-full-audio-or-subtitles-of-glados-sentences

Comment: @Drake That's not a duplicate AT all. That's talking about the sound files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This website: http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/991073-portal-2/faqs/62236 contains the transcript.